# Environmental Variables not accepted for Startup.Auth.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, environment-variables

This is the full source for anyone interested:
https://github.com/josephmcasey/me/blob/master/JosephMCasey/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs

I'm working on building a personal website portfolio using ASP.Net with C#. Currently I'm receiving the following errors which I know are tied to my Startup.Auth.cs class file.

```
    [ArgumentException: The 'ClientId' option must be provided.]
    Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationMiddleware..ctor(OwinMiddleware next, IAppBuilder app, GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions options) +280
   lambda_method(Closure , OwinMiddleware , IAppBuilder , GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions ) +83
    [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
    [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
```

How can I properly call these client secret strings from the azure application's settings without manually typing them into the source?

```
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_Google-clientId"),
            ClientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_Google-clientSecret")
        });
```

Comment: CloudConfigurationManager

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/subodhpatil/archive/2013/08/02/importance-app-settings-in-azure-website-portal.aspx

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Don't you want to formally answer?

Comment: @JosephCasey Now I've to go dinner... maybe tomorrow if no one has done it already :(

Comment: Please, see my answer at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47927227/1690709) link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Fixed Source

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection;
using Owin.Security.Providers.Yahoo;
using Owin.Security.Providers.LinkedIn;
using Owin.Security.Providers.GitHub;
using Owin.Security.Providers.Steam;
using Owin.Security.Providers.StackExchange;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Owin;
using JosephMCasey.Models;
using JosephMCasey.Providers;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management;

namespace JosephMCasey
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        // Enable the application to use OAuthAuthorization. You can then secure your Web APIs
        static Startup()
        {
            PublicClientId = "web";

            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/Account/Authorize"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };
        }

        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

        public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
            // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

            // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
            // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
            // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
            app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

            // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

            // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers

            app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
                clientId: CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft-clientId"),
                clientSecret: CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft-clientSecret"));

            app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
                consumerKey: CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Twitter-consumerKey"),
                consumerSecret: CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Twitter-consumerSecret"));

            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
                appId: CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Facebook-appId"),
                appSecret: CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Facebook-appSecret"));

            app.UseYahooAuthentication(
                CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Yahoo-clientId"),
                CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Yahoo-clientSecret"));

            app.UseGitHubAuthentication(
            clientId: CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Github-clientId"),
            clientSecret: CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Github-clientSecret"));

            app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("LinkedIn-clientId"), CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("LinkedIn-clientSecret"));

            app.UseSteamAuthentication(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Steam-key"));

            app.UseStackExchangeAuthentication(
            clientId: CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StackExchange-clientId"),
            clientSecret: CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StackExchange-clientSecret"),
            key: CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StackExchange-key"));

            app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Google-clientId"),
                ClientSecret = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Google-clientSecret")
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the accepted answer, which doesn't explain the issue - your developer client Id needs to be added as part of the middleware authentication setup.

(I had the same issue with Facebook authentication, and have just realised I forgot to setup my keys when I used a new machine).

As per the accepted answer use of configuration, a reminder that keys shouldn't be hard coded, so either use the **CloudConfigurationManager**, or use the ASP.Net6 "user secret" store via **Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager**.

A good walkthrough of using the secrets manager is:
http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/sociallogins.html

Comment: Could you pls let me know where do you add the clientId for Facebook?  All tutorials only mention to add AppId and AppSecret.
I am getting an error saying ClientId option must be provided.  I went to facebook developer page and couldn't find ClientId setting.