# Error The 'ClientId' option must be provided. When building a docker image

Tags: docker, .net-core

I've started a new .net core project and I configured it to use the Google+ Api for authentication.  My Client Id and Secret are stored using dotnet user-secrets.  When I build my docker image I get

```
 Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: The 'ClientId' option must be provided.
```

I know this is because my secrets aren't being provided to the image.  What I want to know is how can I provide my Id and Secret key without committing them to the repository and still run my image locally.

I was thinking when I deploy it to the server I can have them as part of the Env variables, I guess I could do that locally too, just wondering if anyone else has a solution for this that may be more elegant than mine.

I just can't find much info on how others are doing this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, secrets is not what you should use for deploying. Secrets exists for safe storage during development by helping prevent sensitive data from being storing in code / checked into source control. See related question [How do UserSecrets work in the Cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39743972/2833802)

And you are right, that you should use Environment Variables for instead, or as alternative, some external settings storage like DB.

Comment: Make sure you are running "Development" environment by setting environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development on command line or launchSettings.json  .   If it is not set as Development, then Dotnet runtime won't inject User Secrets.

Answer (score 17):

To Add Google+ Authentication you can see this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?tabs=aspnetcore2x).

Add this snippet in startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
});
```

Add this line in appsettings.json

```
"Authentication": {
    "Google": {
        "ClientId": "ID FROM GOOGLE API",
        "ClientSecret": "SECRET FROM GOOGLE API"
}
```